# Output the given English pronoun table

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Output the provided table of English pronouns exactly, in as few bytes as possible.

#### Code rules

- The code will take no input
- The table is tab-delimited
- Each line begins with a single tab `\t` if there is no row heading
- Each line ends in a single newline `\n` (not `\r\n`), including the last line
- There are four tabs between "Plural" and the newline (`Plural\t\t\t\t\n`) because it refers to the next four columns as well, but no other line has trailing tabs or spaces

#### Spelling rules

- There is no Possessive Pronoun for "it", so the data is "-"
- The only pronoun to use an apostrophe is "one's". "It's" means "it is" or "is has" and is a contraction, not a pronoun
- Some people use "themself" for the singular, gender non-specific, third person, but in this table it is "themselves"
- This table is not complete; other non-standard, alternate and rare forms are not included

#### Output

Use [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/yvurtL85/1/embedded/result/) to check your output.

#### Pretty-printed (do not output this!)

```
                Singular                                                  Plural
                                   Possessive   Possessive                                   Possessive   Possessive
                Subject   Object   Determiner   Pronoun      Reflexive    Subject   Object   Determiner   Pronoun      Reflexive
First Person    I         me       my           mine         myself       we        us       our          ours         ourselves
Second Person   you       you      your         yours        yourself     you       you      your         yours        yourselves
Third Person    he        him      his          his          himself      they      them     their        theirs       themselves
                she       her      her          hers         herself
                it        it       its          -            itself
                one       one      one's        one's        oneself
                they      them     their        theirs       themselves
```

Comment: You misspelled "possessive" the third time.

Comment: SE breaks tabs. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/yvurtL85/embedded/result/)'s a jsfiddle with the requested output; I think you should have something like this to ensure answers are correct.

Comment: @Pietu1998 Thanks for that suggestion. Done.

Comment: @lirtosiast Good pick-up. I forgot to change the second group of headings to match the first. Done now.

Comment: Why is the third person neutral possessive pronoun not `its`?

Comment: @Neil "This is my keyboard" "This is its keyboard" "This keyboard is mine" \*"This keyboard is its". Although it follows the same pattern, most people would say "This keyboard belongs to it".

Answer (score 4):

### [Bubblegum](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 191 bytes

Hexdump (reversible with `xxd -r`), as source code contains unprintables:

```
00000000: a58f 3d0e c230 0c85 67e7 146c 4cdc 0221  ..=..0..g..lL..!
00000010: 3151 512e 508a 4b83 f223 d949 a1b7 274e  1QQ.P.K..#.I..'N
00000020: 5260 410c 4479 9fa3 67f9 4586 56bb 6b34  R`A.Dy..g.E.V.k4
00000030: 1d81 9cc6 44ea 8cbc 14b4 f17c c33e c0a1  ....D......|.>..
00000040: 94c6 3323 b39e 70b5 c580 64b5 43fa 741b  ..3#..p...d.C.t.
00000050: f2ce 4707 471c 0c3e 92f3 7f82 da69 e2b0  ..G.G..>.....i..
00000060: 6a90 d83b d883 45b0 33c8 5caa 8c66 803b  j..;..E.3.\..f.;
00000070: 4264 f091 44f9 91ec 0959 b5d8 7b77 5946  Bd..D....Y..{wYF
00000080: 671f 1751 0617 4ac4 f79e e49c 464d af98  g..Q..J.....FM..
00000090: 1161 d436 89ab 6c4e 0823 ce02 2bd0 54c8  .a.6..lN.#..+.T.
000000a0: d9a9 29c0 329a b6ad e28c 34ab 4087 7219  ..).2.....4.@.r.
000000b0: 36c2 ecf9 b460 d59a df2c cddf bf3d 01    6....`...,...=.
```

Look, *someone* had to do it...

Comment: Is it just my imagination or are your two example non-constant output programs on Esolang exactly the same?

Comment: @CJDennis They are the same. When given one integer as input, the program does primality testing; with 2 input integers, it adds them. (I didn't make Bubblegum, by the way; Dennis did.)

Comment: Sorry! I saw `D` and my brain skipped the rest! "Fails" is an interesting choice of words...

Comment: I think this wins; all this repetition makes general-purpose compression too good. Jelly's compression gets about 250.

Comment: Sorry, I broke your answer by fixing a mistake in the data. It should make your answer smaller though!